# GoogleMapsM4B framework not showing Map

Tags: ios, google-maps

Hi I currently build in IOS using GoogleMapsM4B framework. But the Map is not showing.Any Idea?

step 1:i have downloaded Google Maps Mobile SDK from this link sdk ios

step 2: Create an API project in the Google APIs Console.

step 3: Select the Services pane in your API project, and enable the Google Maps SDK for iOS. This displays the Google Maps Terms of Service.

step 4:i Selected the API Access pane in the console, and click Create new iOS key.and then i added API Key in AppDelegate.m.

I am not getting result. in log i got this error,Your key may be invalid for bundle Id,but when i use  google maps framework(old) it's work fine no error.

> error - **itms-90535 unexpected cfbundleexecutable key**

Comment: **GoogleMapsM4B** is for business purpose, use simple **Google Maps**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik but when i use google maps frame work ,it's show error during upload..

Comment: can u show the error

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik error itms-90535 unexpected cfbundleexecutable key

Comment: now I close ur question and check once the duplicate answer, if it is not useful reply here I reopen ur question ad we go for next step

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i try this before ,it's not working for me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik reopen Question

Comment: ok what else u need for thsi

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i try every thing on this error but it's not working only when i use google mapsM4B framework then no error but map are not showing..

Comment: this help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599840/cant-upload-ios-app-to-itunes-with-xcode-7-and-googlemaps-with-podfile